# How can I disable currency autoupdate in Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

Opencart version: 1.5.6.4

I have a fresh opencart installation, in a shared hosting environment. Everything runs smoothly until I try to log in into the admin account. 
I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Error: MySQL server has gone away<br />Error No: 2006<br />UPDATE oc_currency SET value = '1.00000', date_modified = '2015-02-21 05:56:24' WHERE code = 'USD'' in /home/ajast1ij/public_html/<site>/system/database/mysqli.php:41 Stack trace: #0 /home/ajast1ij/public_html/<site>/system/library/db.php(20): DBMySQLi->query('UPDATE oc_curre...') #1 /home/ajast1ij/public_html/<site>/admin/model/localisation/currency.php(141): DB->query('UPDATE oc_curre...') #2 /home/ajast1ij/public_html/<site>/admin/controller/common/home.php(193): ModelLocalisationCurrency->updateCurrencies() #3 [internal function]: ControllerCommonHome->index() #4 /home/ajast1ij/public_html/<site>/system/engine/front.php(42): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #5 /home/ajast1ij/public_html/<site>/system/engine/front.php(29): Front->execute(Object(Action)) #6 /home/ajast1ij/public_html/<site>/admin/index.php(162): Front->dispatch(Object(Action), Object(Action)) #7 { in /home/ajast1ij/public_html/<site>/system/database/mysqli.php on line 41
```

Making me unable to login. I think it is the currency autoupdate feature that is causing the trouble, I'd like to disable it from the database, but cannot find the relevant table. Help needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting is stored in the `oc_setting` table.

This should disable it:

```
UPDATE `oc_setting` SET `value` = 0 WHERE `key` = 'config_currency_auto';
```

You can reenable it by changing it back to 1, or in System->Settings->Local

However, disabling it is not recommended and the error suggests a bigger issue, possibly a timeout. I'd check to see if your server is allowed to access the API URL: http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GBPUSD=X,GBPEUR=X&f=sl1&e=.csv

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! Plus, I don't really need to auto-update currency because, my store is only going to have only one currency.

Answer (score 0):

it has to do with your server . just change its database engine from MyISAM to InnoDB. try to repair your database on server... it will solve your issue...